# Update sum from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have Items movements to and from inventory table 
and report table.

movements table:

```
------------------------------------
id   | part_number | amount | code |
------------------------------------
101  | 3-80-75     |  55    |  2
102  | 5-88-70M    |  -65   |  1
103  | 1-46-57     |  11    |  1
104  | 3-80-75     |  -8    |  2   
105  | 5-51-54     |  76    |  2
106  | 3-80-75     |  -22   |  1
107  | 5-51-54     |  62    |  1
108  | 1-46-57     |  -3    |  2
109  | 3-80-75     |  -16   |  2
-----------------------------------
```

report table:

```
----------------------------------
id  | part_number  | total_code2  |
----------------------------------
456 |  3-80-75     |   
457 |  5-88-70M    |   
458 |  1-46-57     |   
459 |  3-80-75     |   
460 |  5-51-54     |   
----------------------------------
```

I need to update the report table with sum of code 2 only, 
for each part number.

the result need to be like this:

```
----------------------------------
id  | part_number  | total_code2  |
----------------------------------
456 |  3-80-75     |   31
457 |  5-88-70M    |   0
458 |  1-46-57     |   -3
459 |  3-80-75     |   -24
460 |  5-51-54     |   76
----------------------------------
```

Comment: What are the calculations you do to get `total_code2` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

report table shown in Question had two rows for at least 1 part

so I added a code column to the report table.

only 3 rows are updated based on code 2.

matches expected results after allowing for Question snafu, imho

DDL:

```
create table movements
(   id int not null,
    part_number varchar(40) not null,
    amount int not null,
    code int not null
);
-- truncate table movements;
insert movements (id,part_number,amount,code) values (101,'3-80-75',55,2);
insert movements (id,part_number,amount,code) values (102,'5-88-70M',-65,1);
insert movements (id,part_number,amount,code) values (103,'1-46-57',11,1);
insert movements (id,part_number,amount,code) values (104,'3-80-75',-8,2);   
insert movements (id,part_number,amount,code) values (105,'5-51-54',76,2);
insert movements (id,part_number,amount,code) values (106,'3-80-75',-22,1);
insert movements (id,part_number,amount,code) values (107,'5-51-54',62,1);
insert movements (id,part_number,amount,code) values (108,'1-46-57',-3,2);
insert movements (id,part_number,amount,code) values (109,'3-80-75',-16,2);

create table report
(   id int not null,
    part_number varchar(40) not null,
    code int not null,
    total_code2 int not null
);
-- truncate table report;
insert report (id,part_number,code,total_code2) values (456,'3-80-75',2,0);
insert report (id,part_number,code,total_code2) values (458,'1-46-57',2,0);
insert report (id,part_number,code,total_code2) values (460,'5-51-54',2,0);
```

UPDATE:

```
UPDATE report r
JOIN
    (   SELECT part_number, SUM(amount) total_code
        FROM movements
        WHERE code = 2 
        group by part_number
    ) m
ON m.part_number = r.part_number
SET total_code2 = m.total_code
where r.code=2  --   <----- only update code 2
```

Results:

```
select * from report;

+-----+-------------+------+-------------+
| id  | part_number | code | total_code2 |
+-----+-------------+------+-------------+
| 456 | 3-80-75     |    2 |          31 |
| 458 | 1-46-57     |    2 |          -3 |
| 460 | 5-51-54     |    2 |          76 |
+-----+-------------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It works great just as I intended. Although I was wrong in my example. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

As I understood, you want to sum the code for the numbers that has `code = 2`. You can do that with one sql query and inner join:

```
UPDATE report r
JOIN
    (
        SELECT part_number, SUM(code) total_code
        FROM movements
        WHERE code = 2 
    ) m
ON m.part_number = r.part_number
SET total_code2 = m.total_code
```

Comment: @DrewPierce tell me if theres any mistake. I'm a bit tired

Comment: you must really be tired, you just un-did it. sum on amount

Comment: @DrewPierce i read the question again and i think he wants to sum code instead of amount

Comment: I don't think so, I posted an answer showing results that could only be based on amount (such as a sum with a **negative** number), which match his expected, when you allow for some problems with the question.

Comment: What was missing is GROUP BY , Nevertheless, thanks for giving me direction.